# Cordova - How to change page from android code?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

My question looks stupid at first glance and all my searches pointed out window.location and other JS stuff or the externalWebPage plugin. That's not what I'm looking for.

From the JAVA code, when I catch one specific exception during execution of a custom plugin, I want to force the page to move to "logout.html". I don't want to execute callback.error() or to deal with the error inside code in my webpage in any ways. I only want my transaction to be cancel and a web resource to be loaded in the current web UI.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CordovaWebView offers a showWebPage function to load any url from the native code.

From the plugin you should be able to do

```
this.webView.showWebPage("logout.html", false, true, null);
```

Also offers loadUrl

```
this.webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/logout.html");
```

And you can also use loadUrl to execute javascript so you can run the window.location from there without a callback.

```
this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.href='logout.html'");
```

Comment: Thanks, It's fairly simple and works as a charm. I used the loadUrl() method as I don't want to use the whitelist. 
 
snippet used: ----
  
public void deleguateCompensation(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/timeout.html");
                        //webView.showWebPage("logout.html", false, true, null);
                    }
                });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to add it to your main.js interface so that you can callup page changed () and handle it in your angular code.

This can be a simple onPageNeedsChanged Handler call where you retain the context on page change context and just call it whenever you need.

Or you can call the onError callback from the caller, if it is a consistent error callback context to move you there, but sounds like you don't want to do this route.

So the easiest answer then is to just launch your own Activity with a preloaded web url and a web view. You already have access to the activity, so just make your own native activity with a full web view in it, hard coded url and then launch your activity on error.
i.e. I do it for sending an email, but it could be your own activity

```
  cordova.getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

You may even be able to get a reference to the Cordova web view, but not positive on that, but I assume you could through the tree of objects.

Does that work for you needs?
If not can you elaborate on your hesitation to handle in the onerror callback. It's fairly straight forward. Maybe I can help you there as an alternative? Retaining the callingContext and just using callingContext.error(withkey or instructions or object) is not too bad.

```
 A35ble.writeValueToPodCharacteristic(this.device.macAddress, true, this.bytesToSend,
        function (response) {
            console.log("Success: " + response);
            callbackContext.device.notificationReceivedFromPod(callbackContext.device.arrayBufferToString(response));
        }, 
        function (response) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + response);
            alert("Error Sending NSM Message: " + response);
        }
    );
```

For example I made a cordova plugin called A35ble that manages my bluetooth stuff and in this response I just show alert.